# How to use #available / @available in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios, .net, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I need to check for API availability in Xamarin.iOS - in Objective-C or Swift i could use these calls:

```
if (@available(iOS 13, *))
```

or

```
if #available(iOS 13, *)
```

What is the `Xamarin.iOS` equivalent of the `available` keyword - i couldn't find any documentation in the Xamarin API browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **@available** mechanism was added to the clang compiler for Objective C with Xcode 9. It is modelled on the Swift #available syntax .And it is unavailable in Xamarin.iOS . You can use the following code

```
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(13,0))
{
    //...           
}
else
{
   //...
}
```